# What has caused bitcoin to double in value in the last ten days?

Tags: bitcoin-economy

What is the reasoning behind bitcoin's value skyrocketing in the last 10 days? Why the sudden influx of Chinese investors? Does this constitute another bitcoin bubble?

[image]

Comment: This question is too time centric and up to speculation to to have a clear cut answer, for this reason, voting to close.

Comment: Well you can't say anything in finance with absolutely  certainty, but that shouldn't mean you can't make an educated guess. At least that's what I think; I find this sky-rocketing rather interesting too.

Comment: Almost doubled again in value, in 4 days O.O